# How to abort a continuation from another thread

Tags: racket

Is there a way to abort a continuation from another thread? As in:

```
#lang racket

(define thd
  (thread (λ ()
            (call-with-continuation-prompt
             (λ ()
               (sleep 10)
               (printf "Don't print me.\n"))
             (default-continuation-prompt-tag))
            (printf "Do print me.\n"))))

(magically-abort-another-threads-continuation thd)
```

I am hoping not having to use thread control.
As a more descriptive example, say I want to implement do-only-while-polite like this:

```
#lang racket

(define i-am-polite #t)

(define-syntax-rule (do-only-while-polite body ...)
  (call-with-continuation-prompt
   (λ ()
     (define thd (current-thread))
     (define politeness-checker-thd
       (thread (λ ()
                 (let loop ()
                   (cond
                     [(not i-am-polite)
                      (magically-abort-another-threads-continuation thd)]
                     [else (sleep 0.1)
                           (loop)])))))

     body ...

     (thread-kill politeness-checker-thd))
   (default-continuation-prompt-tag)))

(thread (λ ()
          (do-only-while-polite
           (printf "Hello.\n")
           (sleep 1)
           (printf "How are you doing?")
           (sleep 1)
           (printf "It's nice to meet you."))

          (printf "Bye.")))

(sleep 1)
(set! i-am-polite #f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`kill-thread`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/threads.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._kill-thread%29%29).

```
#lang racket

(define thd
  (thread (λ ()
            (printf "Do print me.\n")
            (call-with-continuation-prompt
             (λ ()
               (sleep 10)
               (printf "Don't print me.\n"))
             (default-continuation-prompt-tag)))))

(kill-thread thd)
```

Note that it's not guaranteed that `"Do print me.\n"` in this example will be called in time before the thread has been killed.  [Synchronization](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/all-sync.html) between threads would need to be done to enforce this.

Comment: The example I gave is crude. What I was hoping was a way to control the flow of a thread dynamically from another without having to spawn extra threads and using kill-thread and such. But maybe using threads is the Way.

Comment: Threads can communicate with each other via channels, so there may be other ways to manage control flow indirectly.

Comment: I'd expect [`break-thread`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/threads.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._break-thread%29%29) to be a better match, but yes, some proper communication is better than that and than some attempts to play with continuations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example given in the question implemented using `break-thread`.

```
#lang racket

(define i-am-polite #t)

(define-syntax-rule (do-only-while-polite body ...)
  (with-handlers ([exn:break? void])
    (define thd (current-thread))
    (define politeness-checker-thd
      (thread (λ ()
                (let loop ()
                  (cond
                    [(not i-am-polite)
                     (break-thread thd)]
                    [else (sleep 0.1)
                          (loop)])))))

    body ...

    (kill-thread politeness-checker-thd)))

(thread (λ ()
          (do-only-while-polite
           (printf "Hello.\n")
           (sleep 1)
           (printf "How are you doing?\n")
           (sleep 1)
           (printf "It's nice to meet you.\n"))

          (printf "Bye.\n")))

(sleep 1)
(set! i-am-polite #f)
```